# How to connect a WPF app to a WCF service when going through a proxy sitting on a different domain?

Tags: c#, web-services, wcf, cross-domain

thanks in advance!

We have a WPF application sitting on a PC in domain A. The PC is set up to point to a proxy on another, domain B.

We have an ASP.NET WebForms site sitting on a web server in domain B hosting a WCF service. The website is HTTP, **NOT HTTPS**.

The proxy server is set up to use Windows authentication and we want to use a specific user on the 30 domain to allow the WPF app to use it. We cannot get this set up correctly for the life of us.

WPF app binding config:

```
    <system.net>
        <defaultProxy useDefaultCredentials="true" />
      </system.net>
      <system.serviceModel>
        <bindings>
          <basicHttpBinding>
            <binding name="BasicHttpBinding_IService" closeTimeout="00:05:00" openTimeout="00:05:00" 
                     receiveTimeout="00:5:00" sendTimeout="00:05:00" allowCookies="false" 
                     bypassProxyOnLocal="false" hostNameComparisonMode="StrongWildcard" maxBufferSize="2147483647" 
                     maxBufferPoolSize="65536" maxReceivedMessageSize="2147483647" messageEncoding="Text" 
                     textEncoding="utf-8" transferMode="Buffered" useDefaultWebProxy="false" proxyAddress="http://192.168.30.221">
              <readerQuotas maxDepth="32" maxStringContentLength="2147483647" maxArrayLength="2147483647"
                            maxBytesPerRead="4096" maxNameTableCharCount="16384" />
              <security mode="TransportCredentialOnly">
                <transport clientCredentialType="Windows" proxyCredentialType="None" realm="" />
                <message clientCredentialType="UserName" algorithmSuite="Default" />
              </security>
            </binding>
          </basicHttpBinding>
        </bindings>
      </system.serviceModel>
```

Website WCF config:

```
<system.serviceModel>
    <services>
      <service name="QuickScripts.Website.ScriptService" behaviorConfiguration="newbehaviour">
        <endpoint name="default" address="" binding="basicHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="BasicHttpBinding_IService" contract="QuickScripts.Service.IService" />
      </service>
    </services>
    <bindings>
      <basicHttpBinding>
        <binding name="BasicHttpBinding_IService" maxReceivedMessageSize="2147483647">
          <readerQuotas maxStringContentLength="2147483647" maxArrayLength="2147483647" maxBytesPerRead="4096" maxDepth="32" maxNameTableCharCount="16384" />
        </binding>
      </basicHttpBinding>
    </bindings>
    <behaviors>
      <serviceBehaviors>
        <behavior name="newbehaviour">
          <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true" httpsGetEnabled="false" />
          <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="true" />
        </behavior>
      </serviceBehaviors>
    </behaviors>
    <serviceHostingEnvironment aspNetCompatibilityEnabled="false" multipleSiteBindingsEnabled="true" />
  </system.serviceModel>
```

We want as much of this to be config only as we can, although I suppose that goes without saying.

We're creating the client in code using the ChannelFactory:

```
var factory = new ChannelFactory<IService>(_binding, new EndpointAddress(_url));

_instance = factory.CreateChannel();
```

We have also tried applying credentials to the factory via Credentials.UserName.UserName/Password, but once again to no avail.

So I suppose the main two questions are, is this even possible (surely is though)? And does anybody know where we've gone wrong?

Answer (score 0):

I had to do this a couple years ago.

What i did is add a new port redirect in IIS and used a random port of my choice (i think i used port 82). Then i used that port to connect to my WCF so instead of `http://MyServer/MyService` i was using `http://MyServer:82/MyService`

After doing that it is very simple for a domain admin to restrict port 82 to only the people that were allowed to use the application.

Comment: So was this an alternative to using a proxy?

Comment: Not in this case but it is irrelevant. The credential to allow access to the service was done thought the port the service communicate through. We had HTTP and HTTPS service working as such and i didn't matter as the credential is done at a completely different level. If you application goes thought default port 80 like 99% of the time and your admin restrict you internet access (port 80 again) the service wont work.